# How can I add my own code along with the code generated by the form designer?

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

When I am working in Visual Studio, and use the designer, VS manages the code for creating and positioning the controls.

But what if I want to add my own code there?

Say I want to use a string variable as the name for my form, or for the default text in a box?  I know I can set this in the form_load function, but what if I want to do it in the designer code page?

When the designer generates this code, it is arranged in such a way that the designer can add to it.  How can I add my own code, or manage parts of the code, without interfering with the functionality of the designer?

Would it work if I moved parts of the code to a different file?  How can I do that?

Basically, I want to **Have My Designer and Code it Too!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio should create the designer as a "partial" class.  Just create another file that is also another part of the same "partial" class.  It will be separate file, but same class.  Also, the autogenerator won't overwrite your code this way.

Comment: It won't overwrite, even if I am defining the size of the controls?

Comment: No it won't overwrite it.  However, depending on what (and how) you are doing, it may override your code.  Where override != overwrite.

Comment: Do I use another InitializeComponent() function?

Comment: What's the difference between doing that and using the code in the form_load?

Comment: I did exactly that.  I created a partial class, as you said, and added my own custom stuff to it, calling it from a "second" function, `InitializeThisToo()` function which is called right after the `Initalize()` function.  My own code lives alongside the other code, and I can "Have My Designer and Code it Too."

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the form and click on 'View Code'. Adding your code there will not interfere with the designer don't worry!

To change the name or any property of a textbox (or any control) simply click on the textbox in the Form/Designer and change any of its property in the properties box, usually at the bottom right of the screen.

Comment: In the properties box, I don't think you can set, say, the default text for a control to use a variable.  You can set it to a configuration setting, but not a variable.

Comment: If you want to assign default text for a control, you can do it in the constructor of your form. For example, `txtBox.Text = defaultValue;` (where defaultValue is a string). A good way to do this is to have your own 'init' method call right under `InitializeComponent` where you could initialize your form with your own stuff but make sure you do it *after* the `InitializeComponent`.

Comment: But that means that the text is being set twice - once with the default in the designer.cs, and again in my custom initialization.

Comment: I want to do a series of calculations to place my controls on the form, but I want to be able to return later and use the property sheet, too, if I like.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve, can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Well, I created this form using QuickSharp, which doesn't have any designer, and I want to re-use the same code in VS - but the code is all for the designer. It sets the X and Y , W and H positions of the controls using functions.  If I put this in my designer file in VS, it will mess it up.

Comment: So you want to adjust the location/size of your controls on the form in the code and see how it looks in the designer?

Comment: The designer can only be used to create a static form with the controls set where you define them to be. If you want to move the controls around during runtime, you would do it in code. You should probably add details to your question to get a better answer. Sorry I can't be of more help, I don't have experience with QuickSharp.